# Vim PHP short tag syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

I'm having trouble getting my VIM to correctly syntax highlight php short tags.

```
let php_sql_query=1
let php_htmlInStrings=1
let php_noShortTags=0
let php_folding=0
let php_baselib=1
let php_asp_tags=0
let php_parent_error_close=1
let php_parent_error_open=1
"let php_sync_method=10  " Sync only 10 lines backwards
let php_alt_comparisons=1
let php_alt_assignByReference=1
```

Is all all set in my vimrc file already.  I can't find any help on noShortTags but changing from 0 to 1 has no effect.

Output from `:scriptnames`

```
 1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
 2: /usr/share/vim/vim72/debian.vim
 3: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syntax.vim
 4: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/synload.vim
 5: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syncolor.vim
 6: /usr/share/vim/vim72/filetype.vim
 7: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin.vim
 8: /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/elflord.vim
 9: /etc/vim/toggle.vim
10: /etc/vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
11: /home/rwalsh/.vim/plugin/camelcasemotion.vim
12: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
13: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/gzip.vim
14: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/matchparen.vim
15: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
16: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/rrhelper.vim
17: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/spellfile.vim
18: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
19: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tohtml.vim
20: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
21: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
22: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/php.vim
23: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/html.vim
24: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/javascript.vim
25: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/vb.vim
26: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/css.vim
27: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/sql.vim
28: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/sqloracle.vim
29: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/php.vim
30: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/html.vim
31: /etc/vim/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
32: /etc/vim/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
33: /home/rwalsh/.vim/autoload/camelcasemotion.vim
```

I was hoping php (line 22) would take care of it.  I have taken a screen shot (below) which shows how it is highlighted with long tags (line 60) and with short tags (line 61, 62, 89-92).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLYEn.jpg)

Comment: Listen to Vim, for it is right. You shall not use short tags.

Comment: I actually agree with you, but my voice is in the minority and the project code already has short tags strewn through out.

Comment: How do you think they should be highlighted?  What syntax script are you using?  Does the syntax script you think should be loading show up in the output of `:scriptnames` when editing a php file?

Comment: @Randy-Morris I've updated the original post  with more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user over on reddit found that VIM's php sytntax only checks that `php_noShortTags` exists.  Simply commenting it out or removing from my .vimrc file fixed it.